# How to set sockets to blocking mode in Windows?

Tags: c++, networking, sockets, winsock

I'm doing some fairly simple cross-platform TCP socket programming. I have unfortunately found out that when compiled on Windows, my sockets are non-blocking by default, while on OS X they are blocking by default. How do I force a socket into blocking mode on Windows? Do they normally default to non-blocking mode or is something terribly wrong?

My code is based in part on these simple examples:
http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/CSockets/code/TCPEchoClient.c
http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/CSockets/code/TCPEchoServer.c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [this reference](http://www.sockets.com/winsock.htm#Deviation_BlockingRoutines) may help; note, in particular, that

> Although blocking operations on
>   sockets are supported under Windows
>   Sockets, their use is strongly
>   discouraged. Programmers who are
>   constrained to use blocking mode --
>   for example, as part of an existing
>   application which is to be ported --
>   should be aware of the semantics of
>   blocking operations in Windows
>   Sockets.

If you're fully aware of the zillion issues listed [here](http://www.sockets.com/winsock.htm#Overview_BlockingNonBlocking), and find dealing with all of them preferable to designing your program to fit in well with Windows rather than being a half-*beep*ed port from Unix, go right ahead with a [ioctlsocket](http://www.sockets.com/winsock.htm#IoctlSocket) call with the cmd argument set to FIONBIO and the third argument pointing to a longword worth 0. But, don't say you weren't warned;-).

Comment: So do windows programmers normally create infinite loops to constantly poll recv and other functions? That seems awfully inefficient.

Comment: Nope, async I/O (esp. network) programming is generally done through callbacks or events, most definitely **NOT** polling, and exactly because of that it's extremely efficient. winsock is in the grand old Win API tradition, so it uses messages rather than callbacks. Or, instead of select, you use http://www.sockets.com/winsock.htm#Windows_AsyncSelect and live happily ever after;-). E.g, connect returns `SOCKET_ERROR`, you checks with WSAGetLastError and get a WSAEWOULDBLOCK, then when you  WSAAsyncSelect w/interest in connections, you'll get a `FD_CONNECT` when ready -- etc, etc.

Comment: Further note that programming right to winsock can bend your brain: Python's Twisted, MFC's CAsyncSocket (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tbz7kf5(VS.80).aspx), ACE (cfr http://www.artima.com/articles/io_design_patterns.html), etc, etc, all offer equally powerful and higher-level (easier to use;-) async/event based APIs to Windows async IO approaches (many with cross-platform advantages as a nice vigorish;-).

Comment: Sorry, but -1 for quoting a Windows 3.1 (!) 16 bit source. This entire line of Windows versions was replaced by the Windows 95 line, which itself has been replaced since. Look at the date on top: 1993! Windows today is pre-emptive which takes away the main blocking concern

Comment: The winsock tag indicates to me that the OP wants to know about winsock, so that's what I answered about (while recommending NOT programming to winsock but to higher abstraction layers, such as Twisted, MFC or ACE: those frameworks, of course, will use whatever's the best implementation available on the specific system they're installed on).

Answer (score 4):

No, plain old BSD style sockets are *not* non-blocking by default on Windows.  See the examples in the [Winsock Programmer's FAQ](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/).

If you use MFC and its CAsyncSocket mess, then yes, it's all non-blocking, but that's a [separate issue](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/articles/csocket.html).